# When (how quickly) is a golang child function cancelled when cancelFunc() is called?

Tags: go, cancellation

I want to access Redis and do a GET on two machines *simultaneously*. I'll use the first result I get and cancel the other call.

What I'm wondering is whether `cancelFunc()` breaks a go function immediately or whether it will wait for a specific event to happen before it notices the signal. The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) just says:

> Calling the `CancelFunc` cancels the child and its children, removes the parent's reference to the child, and stops any associated timers.

That doesn't say whether it happens immediately or whether a special cancellation point needs to be reached.

Any documentation I missed about that particular point?

Comment: CancelFunc doesn’t cancel any functions (you can’t “cancel” a function), it cancels the Context. What you do with that is up to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Canceling a context simply closes its `Done` channel, it doesn't "kill" a goroutine or anything like that. Code that executes under the context has to do a `select` to notice the closure of the `Done` channel and abandon whatever work it's doing.

However in many cases this work is already done for you. If the redis client method you're using to make requests accepts a context, then it's safe to assume that if that context is canceled, the client will handle the cancellation and the method will immediately return an error of `context.Canceled` — all you need to do is handle that error by quitting what you're doing.

Comment: Ha! Okay. In C it would be like setting a `Done` flag to true and when that happens your code can do `if(Done) return;`. In other words, the app that accepts a context needs to be proactive and check as often as possible to see whether it should stop ASAP.

Comment: @AlexisWilke more or less, except that a channel closure is `select`able, which isn't something a flag variable can do. :)